# Are "alerts" in Bootstrap4 blocking? If not , is there a way to do so?

Tags: bootstrap-4, blocking, alerts

I'm trying to "alert" the user if they have checked more than one row in a table.  If length is not  equal to one, I show an alert which can be dismissed.  I don't want to continue to another template until the user dismisses the alert.  However, it seems to be non-blocking.

I have looked for a description of the alert behavior, but I don't see this description of blocking vs non-blocking.

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible collapse" id="selectonlyone" 
  roll="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Select only one row to edit!
</div>





document.getElementById("btn3").onclick = function() {
  var rowids = mytable.rows('.selected').data();
  var pkids = [];  
  var arrayLength = rowids.length;
  if(arrayLength==1){
    ...some code

  }
  else {
    $('#selectonlyone').show();
    document.location.href = "{% url 'show_template'  %}" ;

  }
};
```

Comment: Not sure about Bootstrap 4, but try using a Modal; in BS3, you can set it so they have to dismiss it to continue (`data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"`)

Comment: Yes, a modal is probably going to attract the users attention better than an Alert anyway.  You answered my question and gave me the solution.  If you want points, change to an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I should add that I had to remove the second line in my else clause.```else {
       $('#myModal').modal("show") }``` Upon closing the modal, you end up on the same page to allow the user to respond to the warning.

Comment: By default, modals will pop-up on the same screen you're on; there's no redirecting/changing of views associated, unless your JS code has logic to do so. I'll let you add a self-answer for this one; I simply gave a hint at the process. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they don't block.  At Tim's suggestion, I used a modal instead. The modal doesn't block either.  That is, execution of the "else" clause will continue, but the modal will appear and the user won't be able to move on until they close the modal.  When they close it, user remains at original page.  The modal is probably more noticeable to the user anyway.  Thanks again Tim.

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" data-toggle="modal"  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Warning!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Select only one row to edit!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>          



document.getElementById("btn3").onclick = function() {
  var rowids = mytable.rows('.selected').data();
  var pkids = [];  
  var arrayLength = rowids.length;
  if(arrayLength==1){
    some code...
  }
  else {
    $('#myModal').modal("show")                     
  }
};
```